# Why does setTimeout(location.reload) throw a TypeError?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I'm trying to understand the strange behavior of this code:

```
window.setTimeout(window.location.reload, 200);
```

- In Firefox this throws a TypeError:

  > TypeError: 'reload' called on an object that does not implement interface Location.
- In Chromium this throws another TypeError:

  > Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

---

These two alternatives work fine:

- `window.setTimeout('window.location.reload()', 200);`
- `window.setTimeout(function(){window.location.reload()}, 200)`

Why?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is due to the fact that `window.location.reload` will be called out of context, so the actual function `reload()` does not have any reference to the `location` object.

In JavaScript, if you call a function `foo.bar()`, the context is `foo`, so `this` refers to `foo` within the function `bar`.

However, if you assign `var a = foo.bar` and then call `a()` (which is still the same function), it will have no context, so `this` will be undefined. This is what happens when you pass the function as a method parameter.

The usual way to work around this issue is to bind the context:

```
window.setTimeout(window.location.reload.bind(window.location), 200);
```

This ensures that the function will always be called in the context of `window.location`, no matter how it is called.

There is a nice example in the [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#With_setTimeout).