# Javascript:Why setTimeout(audio.play,500) not working?

Tags: javascript

Javascript:Why setTimeout(audio.play,500) not working?

This is not working(and Firefox 52 said `TypeError: 'play' called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLMediaElement.`):

```
setTimeout(document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0].play,1000.5)
```

This is working:

```
setTimeout(function(){document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0].play()}, 1000.5);
```

Why?also I can't understand that error prompt

Comment: No, `.setTimeout` takes a function definition, not a function call. `.play` would be correct, if, you know, it were correct. I like this question.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5911211/settimeout-inside-javascript-class-using-this

Comment: `setTimeout(document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0].play.bind(document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0]), 1000.5)` would work.

Comment: You can shorten that because you don't need the dom element to find the `play` function, you only need that inside the bind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first example you pass the function directly as callback to the `setTimeout`, but that way you will lose the context in which the play function should be called, as of that `play` is called on the global object, in the case of the browser this will be the `window`.

That's why you get the error message:

> TypeError: 'play' called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLMediaElement.

In the second case you pass a function to `setTimeout` and this function will then execute:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0].play()
```

In that case `play()` is called on the object `document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0]` immediately and the return value of that call (which is definitely not a function) is used as `setTimeout` callback.

Related questions:

- [`setTimeout` and `this` in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591269/settimeout-and-this-in-javascript)
- [`setTimeout()` inside JavaScript Class using `this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5911211/settimeout-inside-javascript-class-using-this)
- [Why does `setTimeout(location.reload)` throw a TypeError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39407803/why-does-settimeoutlocation-reload-throw-a-typeerror)

Comment: I'm not sure,is `you will loos the context` meaning `you will lost the context`?I'm basic accept your answer,but `setTimeout(window.play,1000.5)` is not made this same message(even no error massage).

Comment: @illiteracy `window.play` is `undefined`, so `setTimeout(window.play,1000.5)` is equal to `setTimeout(undefined,1000.5)` that'y why you don't get an error in that case. `document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0].play` on the other hand is not `undefined`, but a function.

Comment: But `setTimeout(document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0].play,100)` still same message when I manually made a `window.play` method.

Comment: @illiteracy `setTimeout(document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0].play,100)`  does not call the `play`  function `window`  has, but calles the ` play` function of `document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0]` in the context of `window`.